# Impala on Hadoop 1.0.4

Tags: hadoop, impala

I am trying to work on `impala` in my linux box. Mine is not a cloudera distribution. I installed `Hadoop`, `Hive`, `HBase` and other components individually.

Here are the versions

```
Hadoop - 1.0.4
HBase - 0.94.8
Hive - 0.9.0
Impala - 1.2.3
```

I installed impala using rpm as mine is a redhat linux box.

I am not able to configure the impala servrer (indeed not able to find site.xml's) in my machine.

In the research I did, I came to know that `impala` will only work with `Hadoop 2.x`. Is it true? If it is correct, I need to migrate to `2.x` rather than wasting time on `1.x`.

Could someone confirm the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use latest CDH 4.x

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_prereqs.html